# Jackson serialize field with different custom serializers

Tags: java, jackson

Is it possible to write n custom serializers for a particular field and then sometimes use serializer A and another time use serializer B? I have written custom serializers before but I have used them by annotation which is not possible in this case. I would really like to avoid something like views since I had to write a getter for each serializer implementation then.

This is what I have:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MongoIdSerializer.class)
String id;
```

This is what I want:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = <SerializerDeclaredByPropertyFile>)
String id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom serializer that you use on the property.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DelegatingSerializer.class)
String id;
```

The implementation would be something like that:

```
public class DelegatingSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String>{

   public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
       JsonSerializer<String> serializer = getSerializer();
       serializer.serialize(value, jgen, provider);      
   }

   private JsonSerializer<String> getSerializer() {
       ...
       return someSerializerInstance;
   }

}
```

In the `getSerializer`method you would return an instance of the correct serializer.